# Initialize tuple with empty or null values in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, tuples, trygetvalue

I have this dictionary and tuples set up in SetValue() as below :-

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>();

private void SetValue() 
{
  var myTuple1= Tuple.Create("ABC", "123");
  var myTuple2= Tuple.Create("DEF", "456");
  myDict.Add("One", myTuple1)
  myDict.Add("Two", myTuple2)
}
```

I am trying to retrive the tuple in GetValue() as below :-

```
private void GetValue()
{
  var myTuple = new Tuple<string, string>("",""); //Is this correct way to initialize   tuple
  if (myDict.TryGetValue(sdsId, out myTuple))
  {
    var x = myTuple.Item1;
    var y = myTuple.Item2;
   }
}
```

My question is whether this is the correct way to initialize tuple while retrieving the same from a dictionary ? Is there a better code?

```
 var myTuple = new Tuple<string, string>("","");
```

Comment: Initializing a tuple has no direct relationship to using a dictionary. The two classes are not related.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If it's an out parameter, the object doesn't need to be initialized before being used. You should just be able to do:

```
Tuple<string,string> myTuple;
if (myDict.TryGetValue(sdsId, out myTuple))
{
    var x = myTuple.Item1;
    var y = myTuple.Item2;
}
```

Comment: Thats so true. I am surely a dumbo. Thanks :)

Answer (score 19):

You don't need to create an instance for an out parameter. Just declare the local variable as Tuple but don't assign a value.

```
Tuple<string, string> myTyple;
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter I honestly read the question as asking for the best way to define the variable for use in that scenario. As such, it just needed to be declared.